# Small pieces of video split by ffmpeg are not playing or playing with artifacts

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, h.264, aac

I'm trying to cut a video file into small parts (0.5-5s) and encode these parts to h.264/aac with ffmpeg. I'm using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.avi -ss 00:05:00 -t 00:00:01,50 -vcodec libx264 -threads 0 -vpre default -acodec libfaac out1.mp4
```

In VLC, some pieces are playing without video, sound only, other pieces had video artifacts like this:

[image]

Maybe I missed some necessary arguments for ffmpeg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried it with FFmpeg version 0.8.5, using an AVI input file just like you.

The following command produced correct results:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.avi -ss 00:00:05 -t 00:00:01.50 -vcodec libx264 -vpre default -acodec libfaac out1.mp4
```

---

Here are some tips to get it working:

#### Update to the latest version of FFmpeg.

For Ubuntu, follow the [tutorials here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095). I've been using them myself.

On OS X, install FFmpeg [using Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation), by calling `brew install ffmpeg`.

On Windows, just download [the precompiled versions](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/ffmpeg).

#### Use the correct length format.

Note that the duration format is using decimal points, not commas, e.g. `hh:mm:ss[.xxx]`.

#### Remove the `-threads 0` option.

Enabling `-threads 0` however gave me the error "nal buffer is too small". I don't even know why they allow a value of zero here, and unless you have a specific reason to do so, I would just leave this argument out. Ideally, it should enable `auto-threads` in `libx264`, but there might be a bug I'm not aware of.

#### Encode without B-pictures.

Depending on the size of the output video, I don't know if `libx264` is even able to reliably produce output using B-pictures that reference one or more intra-coded pictures. This might even lead to the artifacts you describe.

You can try to disable B-pictures (or "B-frames") with `-bf 0`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My ffmpeg version is 0.5.1, it's from ubuntu reps =(. Are you compiled ffmpeg yourself? I will try to cut my video considering your advice.

Comment: @Rnd_d Yes, I did. It would make sense to re-compile from source, which isn't that hard on Ubuntu. There are [*excellent* tutorials here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095), just make sure you open the one for your Ubuntu version. I've been using these tutorials to compile all FFmpeg versions I'm using for Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you very very much! I've compiled last version of ffmpeg usgin tutorials you considered. Quality of encoded video and audio has improved! Disabling b-frames actually got rid of artifacts.

Comment: You're welcome! If you have any questions about the flags FFmpeg and libx264 use, there's [a good guide here](https://sites.google.com/site/linuxencoding/x264-ffmpeg-mapping).